# Devise Invitable testing default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise-invitable

I am testing the method 
`User.invite!(:email => "new@example.com")`

of [Devise Invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) with rspec
but i get the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error:
>          Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

I have already added this line in my **config/test.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3001' }
```

What i have to do to solving this issue?

My rails version : 3.2.14

**EDIT**
This is my test.rb file

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection    = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  #config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3001' }
end
```

Comment: Can you post what your `test.rb` looks like? Also you may need to include `config.action_mailer_delivery_method`.

Comment: I did, edited my post with the test.rb content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution,admit its a bit hacky but al least works, if someone find a cleaner solution feel free to comment.

Added this to my **application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :set_host_from_request

private

    def set_host_from_request
        ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options = { host: request.host_with_port }
    end
```